# Plot function in PGFplots with dotted line ends

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Idea from @Jasper Habicht on this question: [Plotting with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669065/plotting-with-latex)

How can one plot a function, so that the ends of the lines are automatic dotted like in this picture (green and blue functions):

[image: Function with solid line that ends dotted]

Comment: I am asking this question to have a place to post my own solution for future reference. Also it could be interesting to see other/better solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\tikzset{
dotted ends/.style={
draw=none,
postaction={
   draw, decoration={lineto, 
   pre=moveto, pre length=0.05*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength,
   post=moveto, post length=0.05*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength, 
   }, decorate},
postaction={
   draw, dotted, decoration={lineto, 
   post=moveto, post length=0.95*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength, 
   }, decorate},
postaction={
   draw, dotted, decoration={lineto, 
   pre=moveto, pre length=0.95*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength,
   }, decorate},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[dotted ends, thick, blue, samples=50] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph of parabola with dotted ends]

This solution does unfortunately not work with the `smooth` option.

**Edit:** now with fixed length(0.5cm) dotted section to better work with different length plots:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\tikzset{
dotted ends/.style={
draw=none,
postaction={
   draw, decoration={lineto, 
   pre=moveto, pre length=0.5cm,
   post=moveto, post length=0.5cm, 
   }, decorate},
postaction={
   draw, dotted, decoration={lineto, 
   post=moveto, post length=(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength-0.5cm), 
   }, decorate},
postaction={
   draw, dotted, decoration={lineto, 
   pre=moveto, pre length=(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength-0.5cm),
   }, decorate},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[dotted ends, thick, cyan, samples=500] {10+10*sin(500*x)};
\addplot[dotted ends, thick, blue, samples=50] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Parabola and sine function with dotted ends]

Comment: Nice! You could also use fixed dimensions for `pre length`, so that the dotted part always has the same length if multiple plots are drawn.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Now added. Do you have any idea of why `+` works?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669134/plus-minus-reversal-in-the-post-length-decoration

Comment: Interesting. I have no idea currently why this is.